# How to use Outlook interpo to update server and logon information

Tags: office-interop, outlook-addin

I need to create an application that will allow me to change server information and credentials on all pop3 accounts in Outlook.

I was able to pull something out like this:

```
Outlook.Application oapp = new Outlook.Application[];
Outlook.Accounts accounts = oapp.Session.Accounts;

foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts) {
    MessageBox.Show(account.SmtpAddress);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(account);
}

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(accounts);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oapp);
```

However I can't find a way to access and change the information that I need, which is:

- Incoming mail server
- Outgoing mail server
- Username and Password